# Angular 4 Gradient line in chart js line chart

Tags: javascript, css, angular, chart.js

I want to draw a line chart in which the line must be a gradient instead of a solid color in Angular 4 using ng2-charts (an Angular 4 compatible version of ChartJs).

I found that there is a way to do so in JavaScript by simply passing a gradient object to the colors of the chart like this:

```
let context: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canva.nativeElement.getContext('2d');

let grad = context.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);

grad.addColorStop(0, '#fff');
grad.addColorStop(1, '#000');

this.testColors = [
    {
        backgroundColor: grad,
        borderColor: grad,
        pointBackgroundColor: grad,
        pointBorderColor: grad,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: grad,
        pointHoverBorderColor: grad,
    },
];
```

But it turns out that in Angular 4 (ng2-charts does accept only string in these places and gives the following error on doing the above:

> Type '{ backgroundColor: CanvasGradient; borderColor: string; pointBackgroundColor: string; pointBorder...' is not assignable to type '{ backgroundColor: string; borderColor: string; pointBackground
>   Color: string; pointBorderColor: s...'.
>       Types of property 'backgroundColor' are incompatible.
>         Type 'CanvasGradient' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I tried giving the CSS linear-gradient also in the string like this:

```
            borderColor: 'linear-gradient(135deg, red, red 60%, blue)',
```

but nothing worked.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Also if there is some other library using which I can draw a line chart with gradient lines instead of solid color lines, that could be helpful as well.

Comment: are you using custom interface for `testColors` ?

Comment: No. I'm not using any custom interface for `testColors`.

Comment: Hey! Could you please tell us how you did it in the end? I have the same issue...